# How to serve files from the correct wwwroot folder on a server hosting two nginx asp.net core websites

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx

I have an Ubuntu web server at `staging.myexample.com` , running two asp.net core (.Net 6) websites on nginx, let's call the first site `cat.myexample.com` and the second one `dog.myexample.com`.

My nginx config is at the end of the question .

Currently, when I go to `staging.myexample.com`, it sends me to a local asp.net core site for `dog.myexample.com` hosted on port 2001 and if I go to `staging.myexample.com/cat`, I get to see the cat web portal, hosted on port 2000.

That's all fine, except that the issue that I have is that for the css files located in `wwwroot/css` under the cat site , hosted on port 2000, either nginx or asp.net tries to serve them from the dog site, (hosted on port 2001). This means I get a 404 for these files.

For instance, one of my `cat site` pages includes this

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/catstyles.css">`

This `css` is located in the `wwwroot` folder for the cat site on port `2000`, but I think that nginx or asp.net tries to get it from the dog site on port 2001, resulting in a 404.  To prove this, I copied this css file to the dog site's `wwwroot/css` folder and the 404 error went away.

How can tell nginx (or aspnet.?) to resolve `~` based routes such that the files in`wwwroot` folders for cat and dog sites are served from the correct locations?

```
server {
    server_name staging.myexample.com;
        server_tokens off;
    
    gzip off;

    location / {                    
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:2001;           
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    default_type application/json;                  
    proxy_redirect off;
    } 
    location /cat {                 
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:2000;           
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    default_type application/json;                  
    proxy_redirect off;
   
}

Thanks
```

Comment: Can you provide your website config? If I understand correctly, this should just be your proxy settings.